# Generating a newsequentialid using Linq

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, uniqueidentifier

I'm inserting a record into a table where `Id` is of type `uniqueidenfier`. I would like that Id to be generated on SQL server, sort of like using [newsequentialid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx).

To insert a record I'm using [`InsertOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx) method like so:

```
 SchedulerDataContext db = new SchedulerDataContext();
 db.Courses.InsertOnSubmit(courseDomainModel);
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

**update:**  as the answer stated I need to set 'Default value or Binding' property of a column to newid(). Here is the screenshot of it for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the msdn-link above

> NEWSEQUENTIALID() can only be used with DEFAULT constraints on table columns of type uniqueidentifier.
>
> When NEWSEQUENTIALID() is used in DEFAULT expressions, it cannot be combined with other scalar operators.
>
> NEWSEQUENTIALID() cannot be referenced in queries.

That means you can not set it from LINQ, you need to put it in the table definition.

Comment: Correct. Just fyi, SQL server didn't like setting default to NEWSEQUENTIALID() so I used NEWID() instead. At least that was a case in the designer for SQL Express 2008 R2.   Thank you.